# Two Java strings are saying they are equal when they are not

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have two arraylists, one contains Strings and the other contains Classes that have a String data member. The goal is to recurse through the objects in the second arraylist, and find which object's string data member equals a string value in the first arraylist.

Now I understand that you cannot use the == operator to compare strings, so I initially used the equals method, and now I've tried the contentEquals method, however regardless of the method I choose the strings are always classified as equal - even when they are not. So whenever I run the code below, the "if" statement always returns true the first time it is called, regardless of whether the strings are actually equal.

```
Iterator stringListIter = stringList.iterator();
Iterator objectListIter = objectList.iterator();
while (stringListIter.hasNext())
{
    String currentString = (String) stringListIter.next();
    while (objectListIter.hasNext())
    {
        MyObject currentObject = (MyObject) objectListIter.next();
        String objectString = currentObject.getString();
        if (objectString.contentEquals(currentString));
        {
            //Do something here.....
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I get the feeling its probably something that is fairly simple, but I just can't see it.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show what the contents of `StringList` and `ObjectList` are. Can you give an example of two strings that give you the incorrect behaviour?

Comment: Any description for MyObject, specifically for MyObject.contentEquals ??

Comment: Method `contentEquals` for class `String` is unknown to me. Do you have an own `String` class?

Comment: @Kennet: contentEquals is on the `java.lang.String` class. It takes a `CharSequence` or `StringBuffer` argument.

Comment: @Cameron Skinner thanks for info, never used...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is you have an extraneous semicolon:

```
if (objectString.contentEquals(currentString));
```

This statement essentially does nothing so the following block is always executed.

Comment: Okay now I feel like a complete idiot. I must have looked at the code 100 times and never saw it. Thank you very very much!!!

Comment: No trouble. That's the sort of problem that's always really hard to spot :) Incidentally, tools like Checkstyle and Findbugs are *really* good at picking up this kind of bug. I highly recommend them.

Comment: @Ryanvandenbergh you can't feel that bad, about 50 people had to look at the question before somebody noticed

Comment: Thanks guys :-). I am definately going to go try those tools Cameron!

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
stringOne.equals(stringTwo)
```

or

```
stringOne.equalsIgnoreCase(stringTwo)
```

for comparing Strings.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but they still state that they are equal when they are not.

Answer (score 0):

If each object is only containing one string that is being accessed then I would just create a toString() method in the object and use the .Equals() method.

For instance:

```
if (ObjectString.Equals(CurrentString));
    {
        //Do something here.....
        break;
    }
```

And in your object just create a toString() method like so:

```
public string toString()
{
    return yourStringHere;
}
```

Give that a try.

Comment: Thanks that a nice idea, unfortnately I tried it but it still states that they are equal.

Answer (score 0):

try to use objectString.equalsIgnoreCase(currentString) instead of objectString.contentEquals(currentString) and in this code due to semicolon after if statements it gives an error otherwise it would be run properly.